# Access Class Library from Universal Shared App

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, windows-8, win-universal-app

I have an Universal Shared Application which contains some Javascript/Html Code.
See project structure here:

[image]

Now I want to access some native functionality which should be shared among the both projects. 
I tried to create a "Class Library (Universal Windows)" and "Class Library Portal for Universal Windows 8.1" but I can't neither of them reference to the Shared App.

> "One or more selected items is not a valid reference for this type of project"

What am I missing? What are the restrictions for my intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

There were two problems with my approach.

1. You need a JavaScript Blank App (Universal Windows) - i had Windows 8.1
2. You need to use a Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows) for native code

Then you can reference the RTC and use it in JavaScript.

```
var cls = new rtcuw.Class1();
var result = cls.doSomething();
```

Keep in mind, that the function names in JavaScript are starting lowercase, even if your C# function is called DoSomeThing().